# Subset bounded under linear transformation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ and let $B_r[0]=\{x\in \mathbb R^n : \left \| x \right \|\leq r\}$.

Show that $T(B_r[0])$ is bounded.

My proof is: $T$ is continuous and $B_r[0]$ is compact (by Heine-Borel). Then $T(B_r[0])$ is compact. Thus $T(B_r[0])$ is bounded.

Could help with an elementary proof.

Thank you all.

Comment: I think that the proof you posted is the most elementary one can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ in some inner product that yields your norm. Suppose
$$x=x_1v_1+x_2v_2+\cdots+x_nv_n$$
Suppose $T=(T_{ij})$ in this basis. Then
$$T(x)=(\sum_{j}{T_{1j}x_j})v_1+(\sum_j{T_{2j}x_j})v_2+\cdots+(\sum_j{T_{nj}x_j})v_n$$
Let $A$ be the maximum absolute value among the $T_{ij}$ and let $B$ be the maximum absolute value among the $x_i$. Then
$$|\sum_{ij}{T_{ij}x_j}|\leq nAB$$
Thus
$$\|T(x)\|\leq \sqrt{n(nAB)^2}=n^{3/2}AB$$
It follows that $T(B_r([0]))$ is bounded because for all $x$ in $B_r[0]$ we have $B\leq r$.